# List sorting, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, list, sorting

Here is a code snippet, where I am storing the euclidean distance of a dataset by that's respective train row(two lists named train & value) in a list(named L). But when i am sorting the list, an error occurred :

> List sorting, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

the code :

```
def euclidean_distance(x,y):
       return math.sqrt(pow((x[0]-y[0]),2) + pow((x[1]-y[1]),2) + pow((x[2]-y[2]),2) + pow((x[3]-y[3]),2))        

for value in val_set:
  for train in train_set: 
    L.append((euclidean_distance(value,train),train))
  
L.sort()
```

that's how the val_set and train_set are generated:

```
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    data = iris.data[:, :4]
    y = iris.target
    
    val_set=[]
    test_set=[]
    train_set=[]
    L=[]
    random.shuffle(data)
    
    for i in data:
      ran =random.random()
      if ran>=0 and ran<=0.7:
        train_set.append(i)
      elif ran>0.7 and ran<=0.85:
        val_set.append(i)
      else:
        test_set.append(i)
```

can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of val_set and train_set.

Comment: i did it sir , please check

Comment: can you provide `print(L[:5])` just the first 4 elements of the list?

Comment: [(0.5385164807134502, array([4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2])), (0.509901951359278, array([4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2])), (0.0, array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2])), (0.648074069840786, array([4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2])), (0.1414213562373093, array([5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2]))]

Comment: Do you try to sort L ? The problem is that L elements are tuples (distance,train) not a single easy sortable element.

Comment: @PtitXav so what should i do? i have to sort L in ascending order according to algorithm :(

Answer (score 0):

I have given the exact range, which should be sorted. it's solved my problem :

```
L.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
```

Comment: To comment as to why the error occurs, list `L` contains duplicate scores. When tuples with the same first element (score) are compared, the comparison is decided by comparing the second elements, which are numpy arrays. Eventually, `bool(array1 < array2)` is called and causes the error.